# .htaccess redirect subdomain to directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have 2 directories in cpanel public_html folder, one for front (www?.domain.xyz) and the other one for admin section (admin.domain.xyz). What should the .htaccess rewrites look like. I tried the following but it only works for front.

```
DirectoryIndex front/public/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ front/public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do you want to rewrite subdomain to /subdomain folder?

Comment: i want to map with www or without www to front directory and admin to admin directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To map **example.com** or **www.example.com** to **/front** and **sub.example.com** to **/subdomain** folder, you can use these rules :

```
RewriteEngine on

#rewrite main domain to /front folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule !front /front%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
#subdomain to /subdomain folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$
RewriteRule !subdomainfolder /subdomainfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```